# Create dataframe from text files folder FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3]

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text-files

I've been stuck for a while on a very simple problem and I don't seem to find a way to solve it, so I hope someone can help out.

My goal is simply to extract all my files and put it into a dataframe.

I have 6 folders with a bunch of text files in each. I am trying to put them into a dataframe so that I can extract the text file as string and knowing in what folder those files were found.

At first I created a small code to test how many files I had in each folder and everything works fine:

```
path_folder_cvs = '../data/hr/'

sub_dirs = os.listdir(path_folder_cvs)

cv_stats = []

for sub_dir in sub_dirs:
    path_subdir = path_folder_cvs + sub_dir
    nbr_cvs = len(os.listdir(path_subdir))
    stats = {
        'category': sub_dir,
        'nbr_cvs': nbr_cvs,
    }
    cv_stats.append(stats)
    
df_cv_stats = pd.DataFrame(cv_stats)
df_cv_stats.sort_values(by='nbr_cvs', ascending=False)
```

RESULTS works perfectly

[image]

Then I try to set up my dataframe for all files , I have tried multiple trial ALL get the same error and to be clear nothing is wrong with the directory:

#Trial 1

```
`all_cvs_data = []

# Loop through every category of CVs
for sub_dir in sub_dirs:
    path_subdir = path_folder_cvs + sub_dir + '/'
    
    all_cvs_per_category = os.listdir(path_subdir)
    
    # Loop through all CVs in a category
    for cv in all_cvs_per_category:
        
        # Read content of CV
        file_name = path_subdir + cv
        output_string = StringIO()
        with open(file_name, 'rb') as in_file:
            all_cvs_data.append(cv_data)

df_cvs = pd.DataFrame(all_cvs_data)
df_cvs.head(2)`
```

ERROR 1 :

```
`---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_19092/28988059.py in <module>
      5     path_subdir = path_folder_cvs + sub_dir + '/'
      6 
----> 7     all_cvs_per_category = os.listdir(path_subdir)
      8 
      9     # Loop through all CVs in a category

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: '../data/hr/academic_lecturer/'`
```

#TRIAL 2

```
    all_cvs_data = []

# Loop through every category of CVs
for sub_dir in sub_dirs:
    path_subdir = path_folder_cvs + sub_dir + '/'
    
    all_cvs_per_category = os.listdir(path_subdir)
    
    # Loop through all CVs in a category
    for cv in all_cvs_per_category:
        
        # Read content of CV
        file_name = path_subdir + cv
        output_string = StringIO()
        with open(file_name, 'rb') as in_file:
            all_cvs_data.append(cv_data)

df_cvs = pd.DataFrame(all_cvs_data)
df_cvs.head(2)
```

ERROR 2:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_19092/1342318495.py in <module>
      5     path_subdir = path_folder_cvs + sub_dir + '/'
      6 
----> 7     all_cvs_per_category = os.listdir(path_subdir)
      8 
      9     # Loop through all CVs in a category

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: '../data/hr/academic_lecturer/'
```

Comment: Try `all_cvs_per_category = os.listdir(os.path.join(path_folder_cvs, sub_dir))`

Comment: Or may be more simply in line 5: do not add a the trailing '/'

Comment: Thanks for your reply I tried all_cvs_per_category = os.listdir(os.path.join(path_folder_cvs, sub_dir)) it still gives me : FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: '../data/hr/academic_lecturer'

Comment: Maybe try changing `path_folder_cvs` to include the full path like `C:/Users/username/data/hr`

Comment: deleting the '/' Also gave me the same error but still appreciative the help! Thanks a lot

Comment: I think you need find the absolute path of where it's looking. The ".." takes you up one directory from wherever you are and looks for the data folder. But where are you and does the data folder exist a level up? Try `os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), ".."))`, what does it return?

Comment: Thanks blake! Oh yeah its weird when I do that os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "..")) it says its only at the data level but didnt reach the hr folder , how can i fixe this?

Comment: Add this just before line 7 where the error is `print(os.path.abspath(path_subdir))`. What does it return? I think the key is to be sure exactly where you are trying to listdir(). It might not be where you think!